# Escaping a literal string for sed

Tags: sed

How can escape the literal string **#!/bin/bash** in a sed expression?
Curently I have a command in a bash script of the form

```
sed 's/Parametersettings:/HERE/g' outpad1 > outpad2
```

I would like the escaped replacement to go where HERE is written in the above.

I have tried all sorts of / \ and $variables with no luck so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo 'Parametersettings:' | sed 's/Parametersettings:/#!\/bin\/bash/g'
#!/bin/bash
```

or use a different delimiter, avoiding the need to escape the `/` characters:

```
$ echo 'Parametersettings:' | sed 's%Parametersettings:%#!/bin/bash%g'
#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 2):

By quoting your string with single quotes ("`''`"), you PREVENT interpolation by the shell. Use double quotes (`""`) and the shell will substitute variables, etc.

```
sed "s/Parametersettings:/$HERE/g" outpad1 > outpad2
```